# Будильник не срабатывает

Tags: java, android

Пишу код будильника для своего приложения, но он не срабатывает

```
 public class AlarmActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


        private Calendar mCalendar;
        private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
        private Ringtone mRingtone;
        private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
        private Intent mIntent;
        TimePicker mTimePicker;

        Handler myHandler = new Handler();
        Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        final int hour = mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                        int minute = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                        mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
                        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 13);
                        mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                        getReceiver();

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

// убрал код на поиск вьюшек и установку слушателей
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

            mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
            mRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
            mRingtone.play();
            myThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnBeginSchedule:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayExerciseActivity.class));
                    mRingtone.stop();
                    break;

                case R.id.btnCancelSchedule:
                    mRingtone.stop();
                    myThread.interrupt();
                    break;

                case R.id.btnDelaySchedule:
                    mRingtone.stop();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), mPendingIntent);
                    AlarmActivity.this.finish();
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void getReceiver() {
            mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), mPendingIntent);
            mAlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, mPendingIntent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            myThread.interrupt();
        }
    }


public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), AlarmActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("fast", true);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
            context.startActivity(i);
            Log.d("Receiver", "text");
        }
    }
}
```

В манифесте есть вот это

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />

<receiver android:name=".ui.alarm.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Что вы хотите сделать вызывая "будильник"? Если вызвать активность то используйте PendingIntent.getActivity. Если послать сообщение для BroadcastReceiver то нужно определять в манифесте intent-filter или регистрировать программно.